# Why route:list returned error running under PhpStorm?

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

I want from PhpStorm 2023 to write all routes of my Laravel app into text file. I can do it in Ubuntu console with the following comman:.

```text
php artisan route:list >> route_list.txt
```

I've added this command into External Tools:

[image]

But I got errors when I try to run it under PhpStorm:

```text
php artisan route:list >> route_list.txt
                                                             
  No arguments expected for "route:list" command, got ">>".  
                                                             
Process finished with exit code 1
```

But under Ubuntu console this works OK.

**How can I run it in PhpStorm?**

Comment: Everything is correct here. `>>` is a shell feature, not PHP. When you are typing that command in terminal, your shell does the processing of the command: 1) it calls `php` 2) with `artisan route:list` params 3) and then redirects the std output `>>` into `route_list.txt` file. Here, on your screenshot, you are executing the php **directly**, passing the whole `artisan route:list >> route_list.txt` to php process.

Comment: *"How can I run it in PhpStorm?"* Cannot give you an exact command. But: 1) you need to either call your shell (bash etc) instead of `php` and pass the whole thing `php artisan route:list >> route_list.txt` as a command to execute or 2) make a script file (e.g. call it `art_rl`) where you put the actual command, make it executable and execute that command instead.